# How to load a html page from href into a div by clicking a Li inside a menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a ul menu

```
                   <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="../folder/rules.html" id="rules">rules</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../folder/service.html" id="service">Service</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
```

and i want when the user press on a tag the html page load on `<div id=result>` that i have in bottom of this page.

i try that with jquery as i found but the html in href load on new tab there is my code:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(funtction(){
        $("#rules").click(function()
             $('#result').load(rules.html);
        });
        $("#service").click(function(){
            $('#result').load(service.html);
        })
    });
     </script>
```

Comment: you need `rules.html` and `service.html` in quotes

Comment: I put quotes but again html page open in new tab thnx for the reply

Comment: just a note, but that version of jQuery is very old... try using a more recent version.

Answer (score 1):

Read up [`.load()` | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

You need to pass the paths of HTML files as `string`.

Replace

```
$('#result').load(rules.html);
```

with

```
$('#result').load('../folder/rules.html');
```

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment, try this:

```
$("#rules").click(function(event)
     $('#result').load('../folder/rules.html');
     event.preventDefault(); // so that the event does not bubble up
});
```

Comment: i try that to but nothing change thnx for your answer

Comment: @AndreasXatziosHadjiconstanti Checkout my updated answer.

Comment: @AndreasXatziosHadjiconstanti Are you getting any error in the JS console?

Comment: still open in new tab and nothing show in my main page

Comment: @AndreasXatziosHadjiconstanti Check if the path to HTML files are correct.

Comment: ok you have right i have a missing ( on my jquery but with the event nothing happen now

Comment: @AndreasXatziosHadjiconstanti replace the `<a>`'s with `<button>`'s. You dont need an anchor here.

Comment: @AndreasXatziosHadjiconstanti Have you checked the browser console for JS errors? Here's how to do it: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers